# Create custom entry point (link) for Messenger Bots (aka Deep Linking)

Tags: facebook, bots, deep-linking, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

In facebook chatbots, if you look at [this documentation about Entry points](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/entry-points) you see that there is one option: Linking Ads, where you can identify your user in the Bot came from which of your ads on Facebook.

In my application, it is vital to know where my user came from, so I need to create unique links which end up in my Bot with some extra info, e.g. unique id, to help me solve the issue.

My question is how can I do this?

May be at the moment it is not possible to do it directly, but if anyone reasearched what additional parameters Facebook adds to the ads url that they are recognisible is also useful.

The Telegram counterpart of this feature is called: [Deep Linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking)

Comment: @wizkid can you help me with this?

Comment: I need info passed with scannable messenger codes, so the way I'm doing it is by making several pages that the bots are attached to, so depending on which page you're talking to the bot knows what your origin is, despite the pages looking identical. Not sure if this helps you, but I thought I'd mention it

Comment: Any findings for this?

Comment: @PavelBulanov Not yet, I think it will be implemented and it's not available in current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a new feature for Messenger Platform added recently, which might serve the purpose. It's called Referral in m.me Links.

[info 1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params)

> **Passing a Parameter**
>
> A m.me link with an added parameter looks like this:
>   http://m.me/mybot?ref=myparam
>
> The value of the ref parameter will be passed to the server via
>   webhook.

[info 2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/referral)

> **Referral Callback**
>
> This callback will occur when an m.me link is used with a referral
>   param and only in a case this user already has a thread with this bot
>   (for new threads see Postback Event).
>
> To start receiving these events you need to subscribe to
>   `messaging_referral` in webhook settings of your app.
>
> An m.me link with an added parameter looks like this:
>   http://m.me/mybot?ref=myparam. The value of the ref parameter will be
>   passed to the server via webhook.